# HTTP negotiation fails from Windows to Linux

Tags: http, hadoop, curl, kerberos, spnego

I am trying to authenticate my local Windows 10 machine to a web service running inside a docker container. To be more specific, this container is running Hadoop services and a MIT Kerberos KDC. I have installed MIT Kerberos for Windows on my local machine and have successfully gotten a ticket `hadoop/quickstart.cloudera@CLOUDERA` from the KDC. When I authenticate with the same principal inside my container and call this command: `curl -i --negotiate -u :  "http://quickstart.cloudera:50070/webhdfs/v1/?op=GETFILESTATUS"` I get a valid response. However, the same command run from my Windows machine returns this error:

```
Error 403 GSSException: Defective token detected (Mechanism level: GSSHeader did not find the right tag)
```

Can anyone familiar with SSPI/GSSAPI give me some insight on what the problem here could be?

I have the environment variable `KRB5CCNAME=<path to ccache>` set correctly. This is the cURL info from my Windows command prompt:

```
curl 7.52.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) libcurl/7.52.1 WinSSL zlib/1.2.8 WinIDN libssh2/1.7.0_DEV
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: IDN IPv6 Largefile SSPI Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM SSL libz
```

Let me know if you need any more information about my environment setup.

**Update:**

Here is the full HTTP response from my Windows machine when I run the command with the `-v` flag added for verbosity.

```
* timeout on name lookup is not supported
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to quickstart.cloudera (127.0.0.1) port 50070 (#0)
> GET /webhdfs/v1/?op=GETFILESTATUS HTTP/1.1
> Host: quickstart.cloudera:50070
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 401 Authentication required
HTTP/1.1 401 Authentication required
< Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
< Date: Fri, 10 Feb 2017 19:41:27 GMT
Date: Fri, 10 Feb 2017 19:41:27 GMT
< Pragma: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
< Date: Fri, 10 Feb 2017 19:41:27 GMT
Date: Fri, 10 Feb 2017 19:41:27 GMT
< Pragma: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
< Set-Cookie: hadoop.auth=; Path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: hadoop.auth=; Path=/; HttpOnly
< Content-Length: 1404
Content-Length: 1404
< Server: Jetty(6.1.26.cloudera.4)
Server: Jetty(6.1.26.cloudera.4)

<
* Ignoring the response-body
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host quickstart.cloudera left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'http://quickstart.cloudera:50070/webhdfs/v1/?op=GETFILESTATUS'
* Found bundle for host quickstart.cloudera: 0x817220 [can pipeline]
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host quickstart.cloudera
* Connected to quickstart.cloudera (127.0.0.1) port 50070 (#0)
* Server auth using Negotiate with user ''
> GET /webhdfs/v1/?op=GETFILESTATUS HTTP/1.1
> Host: quickstart.cloudera:50070
> Authorization: Negotiate TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAt4II4gAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAKAFopAAAADw==
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 403 GSSException: Defective token detected (Mechanism level: GSSHeader did not find the right tag)
HTTP/1.1 403 GSSException: Defective token detected (Mechanism level: GSSHeader did not find the right tag)
< Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
< Date: Fri, 10 Feb 2017 19:41:27 GMT
Date: Fri, 10 Feb 2017 19:41:27 GMT
< Pragma: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
< Date: Fri, 10 Feb 2017 19:41:27 GMT
Date: Fri, 10 Feb 2017 19:41:27 GMT
< Pragma: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< Set-Cookie: hadoop.auth=; Path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: hadoop.auth=; Path=/; HttpOnly
< Content-Length: 1546
Content-Length: 1546
< Server: Jetty(6.1.26.cloudera.4)
Server: Jetty(6.1.26.cloudera.4)

<
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 403 GSSException: Defective token detected (Mechanism level: GSSHeader did not find the right tag)</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 403</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /webhdfs/v1/. Reason:
<pre>    GSSException: Defective token detected (Mechanism level: GSSHeader did not find the right tag)</pre></p><hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

</body>
</html>
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Closing connection 0
```

In contrast, this is the response from running the same command inside my container:

```
* About to connect() to quickstart.cloudera port 50070 (#0)
*   Trying 172.18.0.2... connected
* Connected to quickstart.cloudera (172.18.0.2) port 50070 (#0)
> GET /webhdfs/v1/?op=GETFILESTATUS HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.15.3 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Host: quickstart.cloudera:50070
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 401 Authentication required
HTTP/1.1 401 Authentication required
< Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
< Date: Fri, 10 Feb 2017 21:15:39 GMT
Date: Fri, 10 Feb 2017 21:15:39 GMT
< Pragma: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
< Date: Fri, 10 Feb 2017 21:15:39 GMT
Date: Fri, 10 Feb 2017 21:15:39 GMT
< Pragma: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
< Set-Cookie: hadoop.auth=; Path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: hadoop.auth=; Path=/; HttpOnly
< Content-Length: 1404
Content-Length: 1404
< Server: Jetty(6.1.26.cloudera.4)
Server: Jetty(6.1.26.cloudera.4)

<
* Ignoring the response-body
* Connection #0 to host quickstart.cloudera left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'http://quickstart.cloudera:50070/webhdfs/v1/?op=GETFILESTATUS'
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host quickstart.cloudera
* Connected to quickstart.cloudera (172.18.0.2) port 50070 (#0)
* Server auth using GSS-Negotiate with user ''
> GET /webhdfs/v1/?op=GETFILESTATUS HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Negotiate 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
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.15.3 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Host: quickstart.cloudera:50070
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
< Expires: Fri, 10 Feb 2017 21:15:39 GMT
Expires: Fri, 10 Feb 2017 21:15:39 GMT
< Date: Fri, 10 Feb 2017 21:15:39 GMT
Date: Fri, 10 Feb 2017 21:15:39 GMT
< Pragma: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: Fri, 10 Feb 2017 21:15:39 GMT
Expires: Fri, 10 Feb 2017 21:15:39 GMT
< Date: Fri, 10 Feb 2017 21:15:39 GMT
Date: Fri, 10 Feb 2017 21:15:39 GMT
< Pragma: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
< Content-Type: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
< Set-Cookie: hadoop.auth="u=hadoop&p=hadoop/quickstart.cloudera@CLOUDERA&t=kerberos&e=1486797339425&s=BqBHGJ+/FxxeSR0ayBXHOrfPkwU="; Path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: hadoop.auth="u=hadoop&p=hadoop/quickstart.cloudera@CLOUDERA&t=kerberos&e=1486797339425&s=BqBHGJ+/FxxeSR0ayBXHOrfPkwU="; Path=/; HttpOnly
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Server: Jetty(6.1.26.cloudera.4)
Server: Jetty(6.1.26.cloudera.4)

<
* Connection #0 to host quickstart.cloudera left intact
* Closing connection #0
{"FileStatus":{"accessTime":0,"blockSize":0,"childrenNum":5,"fileId":16385,"group":"supergroup","length":0,"modificationTime":1459909590753,"owner":"hdfs","pathSuffix":"","permission":"755","replication":0,"storagePolicy":0,"type":"DIRECTORY"}}
```

Comment: does `curl -v` give any more details?

Comment: Do you mean `-v` as in the verbose setting when I run the command? I will add the result to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is very easy in this case. Curl on Windows is compiled with SSPI. When SSPI is requested to perform SPNEGO, it tries Kerberos, which fails here. Likely "Server not found in database" (use Wireshark) and then falls back to NTLM. It sends a raw NTLM token to your JGSS-backed server which rejects the token because

1. This is not a SPNEGO wrapped token, but a raw NTLM token
2. Java does not support NTLM

[Here](http://tomcatspnegoad.sourceforge.net/xref/net/sf/michaelo/tomcat/authenticator/SpnegoAuthenticator.html#L136) is sample code how to intercept this and respond with a meaningful message. Raise an issue with Hadoop.

Moreover, your Curl version 7.19.7 on Linux is extremely old and unsecure, you should upgrade immediately AND the SPNEGO Authenticator on Jetty is broken because it does not respond with a context-completion token. To sum up, the entire authentication should not be trusted because it is faulty. See [RFC 7546](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7546).